# Accessing data on Drupal with external application

Tags: database

I'm developing a native iOS application for a small company. The company has a career website on which they publish job offers. The contents such as job descriptions and contact person information are maintained with Drupal. Is there a way to get the plain data of the contents from an iOS application? I never used Drupal before, please help me.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use module Views to create content listings (http://drupal.org/project/views) with Services (https://drupal.org/project/services) and combine them to web services with the content listings using Services Views module (https://drupal.org/project/services_views).

Also, look at Drupal iOS SDK (https://github.com/kylebrowning/drupal-ios-sdk) for some basic already implemented connectors from ios to drupal. (Retrieving specific single user/piece of content, retrieving already mentioned views etc...)

I would start with downloading and enabling the modules, understanding views (https://drupal.org/node/1911062), then read the documentation for services (contained in the module)

Comment: Is it also possible to access the database directly with SQL queries?

Comment: Accessing DB directly would give you a headache, all the tables are normalized so you would have to do mysql joins a lot. The Services module allows you to simply configure all this without writing a single line of code. I updated the answer. If you find it helpful, please accept it.

Comment: I have one more question. Using the techniques you described above, can I retrieve only the HTML of a site or also the values for each field (e.g. author, date of post, title, body etc.)?

Comment: You can retrieve whatever you need. IMO, the most convenient way in such situation is to create json service with some specific node fields.